# Adding to the Selected Text action menu

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I've been on this for days now, all I'm trying to do is add a menu item to the selected text menu, and bind an event to it. Im selecting text in a `WebView`.

So far, I am able to add an item to the menu either by inflating it, or directly adding a menu item.

```
public override void OnActionModeStarted(ActionMode mode)
{
    var item  = mode.Menu.Add("Custom");
    item.SetOnMenuItemClickListener(new ClickListener());

    base.OnActionModeStarted(mode);
}
```

However, the `OnMenuItemClick(IMenuItem)` inside `ClickListener()` never gets hit.

I've tried to overwrite `ActionMode`, all the click callbacks, all the interfaces and classes I could find, but nothing get's called. I can see the actual menu item, but it does nothing.

I've even tried to set the click handler by using

```
var size = mode.Menu.Size();
var menuItem = mode.Menu.GetItem(size - 1);
```

which still doesn't work. During debugging, I can see that item get appended. I've looked everywhere, and I have found no answers.

Fiddling with `OnWindowStartingActionMode(ActionMode.ICallback callback)` also seems fruitless.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume, you implemented `IMenuItemOnMenuItemClickListener`. When you implement your click listener, you have to derive from `Java.Lang.Object`.

```
class ClickListener : Java.Lang.Object, IMenuItemOnMenuItemClickListener
{
    public bool OnMenuItemClick(IMenuItem item)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```